# In MATLAB is there a way to get the result of find(), on a 3-D matrix, as a jagged array of linear indices?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have a Matrix of size 404x15x15. For each of the 404 pages, I want to get linear indices of the remaining 15x15, but in a way that is suitable for vectorisation. This is easy in a for loop as I can do:

```
vals = rand([404, 15, 15]);
m1 = rand([15, 15]);
m2 = rand([15, 15]);

jag1 = cell(404);
jag2 = cell(404);
results = zeros(404);

for i=1:404
    ind_to_sum = find(vals(i,:,:) <= 0.5);
    jag1{i} = m1(ind_to_sum);
    jag2{i} = m2(ind_to_sum);

    results{i} = some_unimportant_function(vals(i,:,:), jag1{i}, jag2{i});
end
```

Here each element of jag1, jag2 is the list of values in m1, m2 corresponding to the indices where vals satisfies the condition. Instead of using a for loop, I am trying to find a way to vectorise this, which needs a version of find() that allows a specific dimension to be ignored, and then return a jagged array. I feel like this shouldn't be unreasonable, as each iteration of the for loop is completely independent from the others. Is there any such function, or perhaps a different strategy that I could use?

Comment: applying `ind2sub` to `ind_to_sum` should give you the indices in subscript (`i,j,k`). No need for loops as you say.

Comment: that said, `m1(vals(i,:,:)<=0.5)` should also work. Logical indexing is a thing :)

Comment: There are no such things as jagged arrays in MATLAB. `[i,ind_to_sum]=find(vals<=0.5)` will give you your two variables `i` and `ind_to_sum`. How to proceed with vectorization from there depends on `some_unimportant_function`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo My bad, I meant to use {} instead of (), I'll edit the question to clarify. You definitely can have "jagged" arrays, in the sense that you have a cell array of (different length) matrices.